# Loop through 2 list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this 2 list of dictionaries, I was trying to print out all the *name*s from `list1` if they are not found in `list2`.

```
list1=[{'name':'A','color':'1'},
       {'name':'B','color':'2'}]

list2=[{'name':'A','color':'3'},
       {'name':'C','color':'1'}]

for item in list1:
    for ii in list2:
        if item['name'] != ii['name']: 
            print item['name']
```

The output I'm getting is

```
A
B
B
```

I expected it to print `B` because there's not b in list2. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Because of the nested loops, you check `B` in list1 against both `A` and `C` in list two, and it matches neither, so it prints both times

Comment: what will happen when there are two `B` in list1 with different `color` so in that case would result be `{'B'}` OR `{'B','B'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's (obviously) not the logic of your code.  You iterate through all combinations of names, and print the one from `list1` *every* time it doesn't match any name in `list2`.

Instead, don't print it until you know it is a mismatch for *all* of those names:

```
for item in list1:
    found = False
    for ii in list2:
        if item['name'] == ii['name']:  
            found = True

    if not found:
        print item['name']
```

This is the direct change to your implementation.  There are one-liners that can do this using comprehensions, `all`, and other Python capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you sample code was a lot easier to work with and I didn't even have to change anything really :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently in your double for loop you print `item['name']` for a mismatch between `any` two elements of list1 and list2, which is not what you want.

Instead you can convert the names in both lists to a set and take the set difference

```
list1=[{'name':'A','color':'1'},
       {'name':'B','color':'2'}]

list2=[{'name':'A','color':'3'},
       {'name':'C','color':'1'}]

#Iterate through both lists and convert the names to a set in both lists
set1 = {item['name'] for item in list1}
set2 = {item['name'] for item in list2}

#Take the set difference to find items in list1 not in list2
output = set1 - set2
print(output)
```

The output will be

```
{'B'}
```

Comment: Thanks @prashantrana fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over and print in every cases where the match is not found.

You can instead use a lookup in a set which is more effective:

```
for x in list1:
    if x['name'] not in {y['name'] for y in list2}:
        print(x['name'])
```

Using `all()`, you can do:

```
for x in list1:
    if all(x['name'] != y['name'] for y in list2):
        print(x['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the names are unique in list1, you can use a set:

```
list1=[{'name':'A','color':'1'},
       {'name':'B','color':'2'}]

list2=[{'name':'A','color':'3'},
       {'name':'C','color':'1'}]

set1         = set(d['name'] for d in list1) 
missingNames = set1.difference(d['name'] for d in list2) # {'B'}
```

If they are not unique and you want to match number of instances, you can do it with Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
count1 = Counter(d['name'] for d in list1) 
count2 = Counter(d['name'] for d in list2)
missingNames = list((count1-count2).elements()) # ['B']
```

*With Counter, if you had two entries in list1 with name 'A', then the output would have been ['A','B'] since only one of the two 'A' in list1 would find a match in list2*